# Mobile vs. Desktop Games - Upsides and Downsides?

Tags: mobile

what is the opinion on developing a game for Mobile vs. Desktop in terms of monetization and revenue versus time spent?

In my opinion, Mobile has more upside in terms of revenue, but as a developer I am not sure if Mobile is any easier to develop for than Desktop.

Thoughts?

These articles are a good source:

- https://venturebeat.com/2017/07/13/mobile-game-revenue-finally-surpasses-pc-and-consoles/
- https://www.cnbc.com/2016/04/22/mobile-game-revenue-to-pass-console-pc-for-first-time.html